# C# - Windows Service - Continuous Ping Request Timeouts

Tags: c#, service, windows-services

I'm new to C# and object-oriented programming in general. I am creating a windows service which would ping an IP address 10 times every 10 minutes.

If 7 out of 10 requests time out (Isolate Network Blips), it would send an email notifying that the system is down. I have got this part right.

The issue I am facing is with the notification stating the system is up.

The following is my code:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
                eventLog.WriteEntry("Source: Service Started",EventLogEntryType.SuccessAudit);
                timer.Enabled = true;
                timer.Interval = (10 * 60 * 1000);
                timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(methodStart);


        }

 public void methodStart(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {

            Ping p = new Ping();
            PingReply r;
            string s = "SYSTEM-IP-ADDRESS";
            int upCounter=0;
            int downCounter = 0;

            bool sysDown = false;
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    r = p.Send(s);
                    if (r.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                    {
                        eventLog.WriteEntry("Ping to " + s.ToString() + "[" + r.Address.ToString() + "]" + " Successful"
                         + " Response delay = " + r.RoundtripTime.ToString() + " ms" + "\n", EventLogEntryType.SuccessAudit);
                        upCounter++;

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        downCounter++;
                    }
                }

                if(downCounter>=7)
                {
                    //LOG ENTRY
                    eventLog.WriteEntry("Unable to reach the system after 7 Timeouts! Email notification Sent.", EventLogEntryType.FailureAudit);

                    // EMAIL NOTIFICATION


                    downCounter = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    sysDown = false;

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //EXCEPTION HANDLING

            }
            loopCounter++;

            if(sysDown==false && loopCounter>2)
            {
                eventLog.WriteEntry("The Tool Is Up Email Notification Sent", EventLogEntryType.SuccessAudit);

                // EMAIL NOTIFICATION

                loopCounter = 0;
            }

        }
```

What I am trying to achieve is, The ping times out 7 => time(s) and sends an email stating it is down. If the system is up during next 2 executions, send an email stating the system is up (My code sends an email every 2 executions stating the system is up).

How can this be achieved?

**Update 1**: I have the email logic.

**Update 2**: Vibhav Ramcharan's solution triggers a system up notification on every execution of **startMethod().**

The threshold for System Down notification is 70% which is 7 ping failures continuously during a single execution.

Suppose, when the system goes down. An email is triggered which would notify system failure.

When the system is up, the execution occurs successfully twice. Send an email notifying that the system is up.

The above code triggers a system up email on every **methodStart()**. Eventually, spamming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works and does the needful.

```
 public void methodStart(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
            {
                Ping p = new Ping();
                PingReply r;
                string s = "SYSTEM-IP-ADDRESS";
                try
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    {
                        r = p.Send(s);
                        if (r.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                        {
                             SuccessNoti();

                       }
                        else
                        {

                            UnsuccessfulNoti();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    UnsuccessfulNoti();
                }

                }

            } 

             public void SuccessNoti()
            {
                if ((string.Compare(status, "Down", false) == 0) && Successcount >= 7)
                {
                    using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
                    {
                        using (SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient(smtp))
                        {
                        //  EMAIL NOTIFICATION

                            Successcount = 0;
                            status = null;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (string.Compare(status, "Down", false) == 0)
                    {
                        Successcount = Successcount + 1;
                    }
                }
            }

             public void sendfailureNotofication()
            {
                if (failureCount >= 7 && !(string.Compare(status, "Down", false) == 0))
                {

                    status = "Down";
                    using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
                    {
                        using (SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient(smtp))
                        {
                        //  EMAIL NOTIFICATION

                            failureCount = 0;
                            status = "Down";
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!(string.Compare(status, "Down", false) == 0))
                    {
                        failureCount = failureCount + 1;
                    }
                }


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, reading your comment I think you need a static int declared outside the method.
Example:

```
class Program{

     private static int loopCounter = 0;
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
          // code
     }

     public void methodStart(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e){
         // code
     }

}
```

If you need to execute the method twice, you should extract all the method from methodStart (example name: startUpMethod(), after that in methodStart you call startUpMethod());
When you want to call the method again (doesnt matter if its inside the same method) you call startUpMethod() again.
This is known as Recursive Call.
Example.

```
 public void public void methodStart(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e){
     startUpMethod();
 }

 public void startUpMethod()
 {
      //do something
      if(repeat)
         startUpMethod()
 }
```

You should take care of infinite loop

Comment: No, I have the email logic which is working. What I am after is the logic to execute the method twice after the system goes down.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you need to track two successful executions and send an email after a failure. I have added comments in the code below.

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args){

        var timer = new Timer
        {
            Enabled = true,
            Interval = (10 * 60 * 1000)
        };
        timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(methodStart);
    }

    private int loopCounter = 0;
    bool sysDown = false;

    // Used to count the number of successful executions after a failure.
    int systemUpAfterFailureCount = 0;

    public void methodStart(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        Ping p = new Ping();
        PingReply r;
        string s = "SYSTEM-IP-ADDRESS";
        int upCounter = 0;
        int downCounter = 0;


        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                r = p.Send(s);

                if (r.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                    upCounter++;
                else
                    downCounter++;
            }

            if (downCounter >= 7)
            {
                // LOG ENTRY
                // EMAIL NOTIFICATION
                downCounter = 0;
                // The system has failed
                sysDown = true;
            }
            else
            {
                // Before changing the sysDown flag, check if the system was previously down
                // This is the first successful execution after the failure
                if (sysDown)
                    systemUpAfterFailureCount++;

                // This will allow systemUpAfterFailureCount to increase if it is Ex: 1 and sysDown = false (Your success execution limit is 2, which we control at the IF block below)
                if (systemUpAfterFailureCount > 1)
                    systemUpAfterFailureCount++;

                sysDown = false;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //EXCEPTION HANDLING
        }

        loopCounter++;

        // Check if the system is down, if it is up execute the following code for a maximum of 2 executions.
        if (sysDown==false && systemUpAfterFailureCount <= 2) 
        {
            // LOG ENTRY
            loopCounter = 0;

            // Send email for successful executions after a failure, limited to 2.
            if (systemUpAfterFailureCount <= 2)
            {
                // EMAIL NOTIFICATION
            }

            // After two successful executions have occured, reset the counter
            if (systemUpAfterFailureCount == 2)
            {
                systemUpAfterFailureCount = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution keeps sending an email after every execution of startMethod.